# Does curly brackets initialization enforce order of evaluation of default arguments?

Tags: c++

Assume there is a class `T` with the following constructor (only):

```cpp
T::T(int one, int two) {}
```

Curly brackets initialization helps to get left-to-right evaluation order of arguments, like so:

```cpp
T t{ expression1, expression2 };
```

So here we get `expression1` always evaluated before `expression2`. But does the same rule apply in case `expression2` is default argument for the given parameter?

```cpp
T::T(int one, int two = expression2) {}
....
T t{ expression1 };
```

Comment: This very much depend on the type of `T` and what constructors it might have. Is `expression1, expression2` using the comma expression, or do `T` have a constructor with two arguments, a constructor with a `std::initializer_list` argument, or is it a POD-type with two or more members? IIRC evaluation order of function arguments is still left to the implementation (compiler), and that goes for constructor arguments as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude for context, I meant a class with a single (user-provided) constructor with two corresponding parameters.

Comment: It turns out I was (partly) wrong. Reading [this evaluation order and sequencing reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) list-initialization (like you do) will evaluate "arguments" in order, left to right. See rule 10.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I understand the rule for the first scenario (where both expressions are given as explicit arguments), but my question about second scenario, where one of the arguments is default.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind Yes, the same will apply when default arguments is used. It's just that when you omit the default argument, the compiler will implicitly make the call using default argument.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't assume that `expression1` will be evaluated before the default argument.

The rule that guarantees left-to-right evaluation in list-initialization is [[dcl.init.list]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#4):

> Within the *initializer-list* of a *braced-init-list*, the *initializer-clauses*, including any that result from pack expansions ([temp.variadic]), are evaluated in the order in which they appear. That is, every value computation and side effect associated with a given *initializer-clause* is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with any *initializer-clause* that follows it in the comma-separated list of the *initializer-list*. [...]

Here, *initializer-list* and *initializer-clause* are grammar productions, so it's clear that the sequencing guarantee only applies between the *initializer-clauses*, i.e., the lexical components of the *initializer-list*. (But it does, of course, extend to any e.g. implicit function calls that are part of the evaluation of the *initializer-clauses*.)

The default argument is not part of an *initializer-clause* so it is covered under a weaker guarantee, [[expr.call]/7](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#7), according to which the initialization of the parameter `two` (including the evaluation of its default argument) is indeterminately sequenced relative to the initialization of every other parameter, i.e., it's unspecified whether `two` is initialized before or after `one`, and they can't be interleaved.

Answer (score 0):

> But does the same rule apply in case expression2 is default argument for the given parameter?

Yes the same applies here because the call expressions `T t{ expression1 };` and `T t{ expression1, expression2 };` are **completely equivalent**.

From [dcl.fct.default](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct.default#2):

> [Example 1: The declaration
>
> ```
> void point(int = 3, int = 4);
> ```
>
> declares a function that can be called with zero, one, or two arguments of type int. It can be called in any of these ways:
>
> ```
> point(1,2);  point(1);  point();
> ```
>
> **The last two calls are equivalent** to `point(1,4)` and `point(3,4)`, respectively.
> — end example]

Comment: Examples are not normative, and I think this one doesn't make a general claim about such equivalence.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, but I found the next best thing that is in the standard. Still better than having no reference at all.

Comment: Um, no. If there is no suitable reference, we must assume evaluation order to be unspecified.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Not applicable as there is a perfectly valid/suitable reference here.

Comment: As long as `T t{ expression1 };` and `T t{ expression1, expression2 };` are equivalent, this makes sense.